# UI not updating even though function is getting called (¿race condition?)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class `BluetoothService` which uses threads to do it's tasks. I make an instance of it in my `MainActivity`, inside the companion object. With that, I can also use the same instance of the class in `NotificationListener`, which is as `NotificationListenerService`. Because of being a `NotificationListenerService`, it's always running in the background. That makes my `BluetoothService` instance to be always alive even after closing the app. The `BluetoothService` instance tells `MainActivity` some state changes with a handler (because actions happen inside threads). So the problem here is that after connecting to the bluetooth device and closing the app, the device remains connected because of `NotificationListener` running in the background. And here is where the strange issues appear. When I click on disconnect, for example, it disconnects from the device and calls the updateUi function (I know this function is called because I add a log and it shows). But UI is not updating. What may be happening? I'm not adding any code because I don't know where the issue could be, I think it's more of a conceptual error I'm avoiding. But feel free to ask for the parts of the code you think may help solve the issue

**Try it on your own:**

Create a new Android Studio (latest version) project, min API 21, package `com.example.sample`.

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside `<application>` tag:

```
<service
    android:name=".NotificationListener"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

`MainActivity.kt` should be:

```
package com.example.sample

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Message
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        val bluetoothService: BluetoothService = BluetoothService()
        var handler: Handler? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (handler == null) {
            handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                override fun handleMessage(inputMessage: Message) {
                    updateState()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        updateState()
    }

    private fun updateState() {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test).text = when (bluetoothService.connectionState) {
            BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTING -> "Connecting"
            BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED -> "Connected"
            else -> "Not connected"
        }
    }

    fun connect(view: View) {
        bluetoothService.connect()
    }

    fun disconnect(view: View) {
        bluetoothService.disconnect()
    }

}
```

A new class, called `BluetoothService`, containing:

```
package com.example.sample

class BluetoothService {

    companion object {
        const val STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0
        const val STATE_CONNECTING = 1
        const val STATE_CONNECTED = 2
    }

    var connectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED

    private fun updateConnectionState(state: Int) {
        connectionState = state
        MainActivity.handler?.obtainMessage(connectionState)?.sendToTarget()
    }

    fun connect() = ConnectThread().start()

    fun disconnect() = updateConnectionState(STATE_DISCONNECTED)

    private inner class ConnectThread : Thread() {

        init {
            sleep(1000)
            updateConnectionState(STATE_CONNECTING)
        }

        override fun run() {
            sleep(1000)
            updateConnectionState(STATE_CONNECTED)
        }

    }
}
```

And a class `NotificationListenerService` with:

```
package com.example.sample

import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification

class NotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        MainActivity.bluetoothService // using the service here makes it stay always alive
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {}

}
```

And make your activity_main.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not connected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test"
        android:onClick="connect"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Disconnect"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test2"
        android:onClick="disconnect"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now try. Connect makes the text show connecting and then connected. Disconnect button makes it go back to not connected. Go to your device settings and give this app notification access. Now go to the app again and click connect button. Connecting and then connected shows. Close the app (recents and swipe, completely closed, don't force stop). Now go again to the app and it says connected. Click on disconnect button and boom, nothing happens, text not updated but function is running. You can add a log to updateState function and see it shows up. Really strange

Comment: Please make a minimal, verifiable and complete example, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @marstran added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I actually figured it out. The problem was the `if (handler == null)` check in `MainActivity -> onCreate`. Seems like handler was left from last execution so everything was running but the UI changes weren't applying on the actual UI. Weird, but seems reasonable